# Approximate Unit: Boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a Banach algebra $A$.

Consider a onesided approximate unit:
$$e:\Lambda\to A:\quad ae_\lambda\stackrel{\lambda}\to a\quad(\forall a\in A)$$

Does it follow that it is eventually bounded:
$$\exists\lambda_0\in\Lambda:\quad\sup_{\lambda\geq\lambda_0}\|e_\lambda\|<\infty$$
What about it in the C*-algebra case?

Clearly the restriction to eventual boundedness is inevitable as
otherwise there are trivial counterexamples merely due to the order on the index set.

(I couldn't come up with construction that works so far..)

Comment: In general this is not true, see for example http://msp.org/pjm/1973/46-1/pjm-v46-n1-p22-s.pdf. Banach algebras with bounded approximate unit have a nice factorization property which not every Banach algebra satisfies.
 For $C^*$-algebras I have to think. Do you make any assumptions (like increasing) about your approximate unit ?

Comment: Ok so Banach Algebras with bounded approximate unit have a factorization property, but are there at all unbounded approximate units? Do you maybe know a Banach algebra that does not possess an according approximation property but still admit an approximate unit anyway?

Comment: No, no assumption as increasing, positive or selfadjoint but only the mere naked approximation property.

Comment: By the way thanks for the nice reference!! :)